# add active class to menu based on url but not to parent

Tags: jquery

i'm having one issues with the following code:

```
$(function() {
    var links = $('.menu li a');
    var page_url = location.href;

    links.each(function(){
        var link_url = $(this).attr('href'); 

        if(page_url.indexOf(link_url) !== -1) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Basically what is happening i have a side menu on my site:

Main page : /main-page

sub page : /sub-page

sub page : /sub-page

sub page : /sub-page

however when i'm inside the subpage this code is also adding the active class to the main page which in the URL is a parent of the home page example:

example.com/main-page/sub-page

i need to add active class to the sub-page not to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You should split the url as following :

```
 splitted_url = page_url.split("/");
```

Get the last part of it (so it will be the last page/sub-page into the url hierarchy based on your url rules), and do your condition with the last part of the url as following :

```
 if(splitted_url[splitted_url.length - 1].indexOf(link_url) !== -1) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
```

Comment: that didn't work but i've used some of your code and fixed so thank you! 
basically i had to split the link url on the menu item also

Comment: Well, what was into the link_url wasn't specified in your question, couldn't advise you to do so without knowing :) Can you accept the answer (yours) to notify everyone that there is no need to help you furthermore ?

Comment: i can only accept my answer tomorrow... but thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

i've used the above suggestion and implemented some changes as it wasn't working properly, i had to split the href on the links and match them, then it worked fine

```
$(function() {
    var links = $('.menu li a');
    var page_url = location.href;
    var splitted_url = page_url.split("/");

    links.each(function(){
        var link_url = $(this).attr('href');
        var splitted_link = link_url.split("/");
        link_url = splitted_link[splitted_link.length -1];
        if(splitted_url[splitted_url.length - 1] == link_url) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```